# In graphviz how to force a straight edge between two nodes?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Here is my graphviz code:

```
digraph G {
  rankdir="LR"
  node [shape=square]
  exDNS [label="External DNS"]
  inDNS [label="Internal DNS"]
  tm [label="Traffic Manager"]
  pri [label="App Service\nPrimary Region"]
  sec [label="App Service\nSecondary Region"]
  Browser -> {inDNS,exDNS} -> Imperva-> tm -> {pri,sec}
  Browser -> Imperva -> {pri,sec}
}
```

It produces the following result:
[image]
I would the edge `Browser -> Imperva` to go straight between the nodes `External DNS` and `Internal DNS`.

How can I do it?

I am using the dot renderer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to make edges behave (explicitly position them).  But by attaching edges to ports, you can have some influence on edge locations.
I think this is what you're after:

```
digraph G {
  rankdir="LR"
//  graph [splines=polyline]
  node [shape=square]
  exDNS [label="External DNS"]
  inDNS [label="Internal DNS"]
  tm [label="Traffic Manager"]
  pri [label="App Service\nPrimary Region"]
  sec [label="App Service\nSecondary Region"]
  Browser:ne -> exDNS -> Imperva
  Browser:e -> Imperva 
  Browser:se -> inDNS -> Imperva
  Imperva-> tm -> {pri,sec}
  Imperva -> {pri,sec}
}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not understand what you have changed in my code.

Comment: I added (tail) ports (https://graphviz.gitlab.io/doc/info/attrs.html#k:portPos) to the three edges starting from Browser.  This helped open the gap between External DNS and Internal DNS.

Comment: Oh, now I can see it - **Browser:ne**. Got it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without fiddling about with ports.

Your current dot first explicitly defines exDNS and inDNS, then Imperva is implicitly defined in the edges - i.e. it's defined third.

All I've added in the dot below is the explicit declaration of node `Imperva` between `exDNS` and `inDNS`, i.e. so it is defined second, before inDNS.

I think this works because there's this wording in the [dotguide](https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf) section 2.6 (NOTE in these words rankdir is the default top-to-bottom so for rankdir=LR read left as top and right as bottom) :

```
If a subgraph has ordering=out, then out-edges within the subgraph that have the same tail node wll fan-out from left to right in their order of creation.
```

TBH I'm not completely sure this is the reason because the dotguide doesn't give a default for `ordering`.

Regardless of the dotguide, in my dot below if I move the definition of `Imperva` up one line to be above the `exDNS` node declaration then the edge from `Browser` to `Imperva` passes over `exDNS` (because `Imperva` is defined first). Move the definition of node `Imperva` below the line for `inDNS` - or omit this explicit definition of the node completely like your dot does - so Imperva is defined after inDNS, and the edge goes below `inDNS` like your graph.

```
digraph G {
  rankdir="LR"
  node [shape=square]
  exDNS [label="External DNS"]
    Imperva;
  inDNS [label="Internal DNS"]
  tm [label="Traffic Manager"]
  pri [label="App Service\nPrimary Region"]
  sec [label="App Service\nSecondary Region"]
  Browser -> {inDNS,exDNS} -> Imperva-> tm -> {pri,sec}
  Browser -> Imperva -> {pri,sec}
}
```

produces:

[image: image produced using dot.exe -Tpng -O graph.dot]